# Pythontex Warning: "DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \m"

Tags: warnings, emacs, pythontex

When using `pythontex` with `sagefamily` like in the example below, I get the following warning:

```
This is PythonTeX 0.18

----  Messages for sage:default:default  ----
  /usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex_utils.py:231: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \m
    '''

--------------------------------------------------
PythonTeX:  Sage_Warning - 0 error(s), 0 warning(s)
```

What does this warning mean and how can I get rid of it?

If I can't get rid of it is there at least a way to prevent emacs from showing this message each time I compile it (after changing the sage code) from emacs?

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[gobble=auto,usefamily=sage]{pythontex}

\begin{document}

\begin{sagecode}
a = 2
b = 3
\end{sagecode}

\(\sage{a}\)

\end{document}
```

Run `pdflatex myfilename.tex` and then `pythontex myfilename.tex` to reproduce the warning (to reproduce it a second time you either have to change the sagecode block or remove the directory `pythontex-files-myfilename` and then execute `pythontex myfilename.tex` again).

```
pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.23 (TeX Live 2021)
kpathsea version 6.3.3
Copyright 2021 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.03
```

```
sage --version
SageMath version 9.2, Release Date: 2020-10-24
```

Comment: The problem doesn't have anything to do with the LaTeX or Sage side of things, it seems to be a Python warning about text in a triple quote documentation string in the source of Pythontex, which contains a line starting with `\mathchoice`. Python interprets `\m` as an escape sequence, which it is not. I think this can be fixed by making the documentation a raw string, i.e., `r"""`. The best way to solve this is to open an issue on https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Marijn mentioned in the comments, this is a pure Python warning due to the fact that the `pythontex` author accidentally used the escape sequence `\m` in a docstring (writing `\mathchoice`).

As the error tells you, the problem occurs in [`pythontex_utils.py` on line 231](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/blob/5befae6c4fc91b399bb583bbb36ade71c2207ab6/pythontex/pythontex_utils.py#L231). In that line a docstring starts that contains multiple unescaped backslashes leading to accidental escape sequences (not just `\m`, by the way). In order to fix this, the `pythontex` author should either escape each backslash or make the docstring "raw" by prepending an `r` to the opening quotes.

Since this is easy to fix, the author will probably do so swiftly if you report it in the project's [issue tracker](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues).

Comment: Thanks, I opened a bug report [here](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/issues/196).